# PostgreSQL рандомный элемент

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица PostgeSQL со словами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо вернуть одно рандомное слово из этой таблицы.

Вот код сервера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сгенерь рандомный id (число) на стороне сервера и по этому id сделай `select ... where id = randomId`. Пойдет? Перед этим мб придется сделать два запроса на мин и мах

Comment: А в чем конкретно заключается вопрос ? Приведенный вами код как раз получает одно рандомное слово.

Comment: Не получает. Он крашится

Comment: Если что то крашится то надо указать точно все сообщения об ошибках. мы не экстрасенсы, по фотографиям кода не лечим

Comment: Потестил данный запрос на БД - все работает. Может не правильное имя таблицы или еще что то? Приведите лог.

Comment: @Алексейг а я правильно обрабатываю resultSet? Он всегда возвращает одно слово

Comment: @karvetskiy с данным запросом он и должен всегда возвращать одно слово или null

Comment: Код выглядит как в примерах по java, по идее должен работать. java обычно обо всех ошибках очень(слишком) подробно сообщает. Напишите в тексте вопроса что именно она сообщает при краше

Comment: @Mike как выяснилось, была ошибка в названии, все решил, все работает. Спасибо за понимание и уделенное время

Comment: @Алексейг как выяснилось, была ошибка в названии, все решил, все работает. Спасибо за понимание и уделенное время

Answer (score 0):

Если вы боитесь разрывов, то можно переписать чутка запрос из ответа выше, используя функцию [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-window.html).

суть запроса - мы для каждой строки в базе проставляем row_number, берем рандомное значение между 1 и количеством строк и выводим это значение.

Примерно выгляд так

```
with data_size as (
    select count(*) from t
),
with rands as (
    values( floor(random() * data_size.count ))
)
select id, word, row_number over(order by id) as rn
from table
where rn = rands
```

p.s. запрос может быть синтаксически невалиден, но демонстрирует нужную логику

Answer (score -3):

1. Как предложил @learp сгенерить на сервере рандомный id и подставить его в запрос
2. В самом запросе с помощью конструкции `with`:

   ```
   with rands(rand) as (
       values (floor(random() * (7 - 3)) + 3)
   )
   select id, word from t, rands where id = rand;
   ```

Comment: А что будет когда в таблице появятся новые записи и что если в id будут разрывы (это абсолютно нормальная ситуация в БД) ?

Comment: Пример дан для таблице в вопросе.

Comment: Код не имеет права зависеть от конкретного состояния таблицы. Что либо пишут в БД для того что бы это можно было изменить без изменения кода

Comment: Это часть Таблицы для примера

Comment: А еще, как выясняется запрос в вопросе рабочий, а проблема где то в java коде, получающем значение из БД ... так что ответ кроме того что работает только с таблицей из 5 записей еще и совершенно не по теме вопроса